# Multiple Tags with RFID then play media from RPi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, rfid

I was wondering if it is at all possible for an RFID reader to read an NFC tag, then ignore that tag, while still being available for other tags which are placed in sequence?

The project is a board game I am working on. The idea is to trigger a media file when an NFC tag is detected by an RFID reader built into the gameboard. That tag remains on the gameboard. As new tags are added to the board each would play a separate media file, whilst the previous tags are still present and no longer trigger a reaction from the RFID reader.

Ideally the project would flow like this:

- A tag is placed on the 'RFID reader/gameboard' which triggers a sound/video clip (from RPi/Arduino?). The tag is not removed from the RFID reader/gameboard.
- A second/third/fourth...tag is placed on the RFID reader/gameboard and each different tag causes a different media file to play.
- Once a tag has generated its corresponding media file to play, its signal would be 'ignored' while the RFID reader waits for next tag.

In summary: Can an RFID reader ignore a tag once detected, not react to it again while it is still within its 'field', but also be available for reading a new tag?

Answer (score 0):

If the reader can handle [multiple tags](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14066?_ga=2.44734116.1499907232.1647368750-179777464.1647368750), then this is easily achievable in software.
Simply keep a list of what is on the board, and only play a sound when a new one is added to the list.